# I get an error in start using when I run python examples/simulate.py

Tags: flow-project

I am new in flow. I start using flow by following steps in https://flow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_setup.html. I get an error in start using when I run python examples/simulate.py ring. I attach my pic error herein.

I think it because of the fact that it must run in linux not windows and the addresses are specified as linux address.

error picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using Flow. It seems like in your windows machine, the command `netconvert -c PATH ....` for some reason is not recognized.

To debug this, you should try running that command separately in your terminal and see what part of it goes wrong.

In any case, that part of the code is written in `flow/core/kernel/network/traci.py` line 512:

```
        subprocess.call(
            [
                'netconvert -c ' + self.net_path + self.cfgfn +
                ' --output-file=' + self.cfg_path + self.netfn +
                ' --no-internal-links="false"'
            ],
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            shell=True)
```

Comment: Hi Ashkan,thanks for your reply. when I run netconvert, I get error for the last part of the command: --no-internal-links=\"false\ and when I delete this part I can run command. what do you think about that?

Comment: @Saeedeh I do not have any idea about that. Sorry :) 
Maybe this link will be useful, in case you have not seen it yet https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/NETCONVERT.html.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that my PATH environment variable didn't contain the SUMO_HOME path(for example, in my case the SUMO_HOME path was /home/akshita/sumo_binaries/bin). Once you add that for example by using `export PATH=$SUMO_HOME:$PATH`,  then you should be good.